# pandas grouping multiple column data at a column level

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group data of a column A, B, C, and D on Report column.

```
report  A  B  C  D
1       1  0  0  0
1       0  1  0  0
2       0  0  0  1
2       0  0  1  0
3       1  0  0  0
3       0  1  0  0     
4       0  0  1  0      
4       1  0  0  0
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve

```
report  A  B  C  D
1       1  1  0  0
2       0  0  1  1
3       1  1  0  0 
4       1  0  1  0
```

Is there any straight forward way to achieve the result?
Thank you very much!!
I appreciate any support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `sum` in the pandas library. The script below outputs the expected results.

```
import pandas as pd

report = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
B = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
C = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
D = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(report, A, B, C, D)), columns = ['report', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df.groupby(['report']).sum())
```